# Nuspec - Why is "contentFiles" ignored if you add "files" node? How to fix?

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

I have a nuspec file for a package containing UWP as well as Android and iOS assemblies.

In the UWP version I also need to include a content file. 
According to [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#including-content-files), I should use the contentFiles tag, which works fine in the following code and in the generated package file I have the files added:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    <id>x</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <authors>...</authors>
    <description>...</description>       
   <contentFiles>        
        <files include="**/images/*.*" ... />        
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

However, I also need to include assemblies, for which I have to use the **files** node:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    ...
  </metadata>  
  <files>
    <file src="..." target="..." />    
  </files>  
</package>
```

In this case, the content files are just ignored. In other words, as soon as I add the **files** node, the contentFiles node is not even added to the generated package!

Is this a bug in Nuget.exe? Is this by design? How can I have both in the package?!

PS: My nuget.exe is the latest official one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, under the *Including content files*, you should use one or the other, as the `ContentFiles` is for the project.json

Try to move your content to your file tag, it should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
        ...
    </metadata>  
    <files>
        <file include="**/images/*.*" target="Content" />
        <file src="..." target="..." />    
    </files>  
</package>
```

Comment: It would have been nice to get at least a warning when you use both elements.

Answer (score 0):

There's a related github issue for NuGet.
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1980

Comment: Thanks Bernard. But that issue seems like a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `files` section to your nuspec file, you then need to manually list all of the files you want in your package, including the content files you've listed in the `contentFiles` section.

Comment: That is what I've done. In the code above "..." refers to that.

Comment: Can you update your code to actually reflect that then? Your examples show one or the other, but not both. It's hard to figure out what the problem might be without seeing the actual file. To be able to help you further, here's what I'd like to see: 1. Your full "before" nuspec 2. Your full "after" nuspec 3. The layout of the actual files on disk.

Comment: It's basically the first code plus the "files" element from the second one.

Comment: Your current files section doesn't show the actual files, you've left out the important bits by showing it as "..." instead. Like I said before, seeing your actual file, with the real values, would be very helpful.